# How to pass ngFor index to class variable to use in global scope ANGULAR 11

Tags: angular, templates, indexing, ngfor, angular11

I can't find a way of passing the index value of a for loop from the template to a variable inside the component class. So I can use that index outside of the blocked scope. Does anyone know how?

```
<div *ngFor="let x of y; index as i">
</div>

<div>{{i}}</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It doesn't sound elegant. The `index` local variable is locally scoped to the enclosed tags.

Comment: I'm looping through an array of objects, the first div needs to contain the references to the image and the second div needs to contain the caption. I can't allocate the caption inside the same div due to the npm package I'm using. It messes everything up.

Comment: So the second `<div>` also needs to be iterated accd. to the array?

Comment: That's correct. The caption sits inside each object, so I need to track the idnex and get the correct caption per image. But I can't think of any way of storing the index globally.

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Comment: it sounds like you're using some kind of carousel that iterates over an array you pass into it, and you're trying to add additional functionality the carousel doesn't provide.  You're going to need to figure out if it actually does provide the functionality (captions?), or extend it or use another package.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop using the `<ng-container>` tag and use the value multiple times.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of y">
  <div> {{ x?.image }} </div>
  <div> {{ x?.caption }} </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: That unfortuantely repeats the image carousel n times

Comment: I sense a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) here. You might have to provide the actual issue to come up with a solution. There isn't enough information now to understand the issue.